# Running Windows Command Prompt using R

Tags: windows, rstudio, command-prompt

I am rather new to Windows Command Prompt. May I know if it is possible to run windows command Prompt using R?

Ie,
I would like to use R to input a command into windows command prompt.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In R you can execute any system command using [`system2`](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#System-commands). The command for the windows command prompt is `cmd`. You could then pass arguments using the `args` parameter of `system2`.

If your arguments include quotes `"` you need to escape them using `\`, e.g. `system2("cmd", args = c("/c", "echo", "hello \"world\""))`, which executes `cmd` passing `/c` as first argument which lets `cmd` execute `echo` passing `hello "world"` as argument.

Your command should thus probably look like:

```
system2("cmd.exe", args = "/c java -mx150m -cp \";\" edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser -outputFormat \"penn,typedDependencies\" -outputFormatOptions \"basicDependencies\" edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz ./Test/input.txt")
```

Note that you can invoke `java` directly. To make the whole thing a bit more readable, you could use it like this:

```
mx <- "-mx150m"
cp <- "-cp \";\" edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser"
of <- "-outputFormat \"penn,typedDependencies\""
oo <- "-outputFormatOptions \"basicDependencies\""
i <- "edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz"
o <- "./Test/input.txt"

system2("java", args = c(mx, cp, of, oo, i, o))
```

Comment: system2("cmd.exe", args = "java -mx150m -cp "*;" edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser -outputFormat "penn,typedDependencies" -outputFormatOptions "basicDependencies" edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz ./Test/input.txt")
Error: unexpected ';' in "system2("cmd.exe", args = "java -mx150m -cp "*;"
> system2("cmd.exe", args = "java -mx150m -cp "*//;" edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser -outputFormat "penn,typedDependencies" -outputFormatOptions "basicDependencies" edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz ./Test/input.txt")

Comment: I tried to run this command which works well on my command prompt and I got this error. Do you know why such error would appear?