# Setting Directory of command prompt

Tags: r, cmd, command-prompt

I would like to set the working directory of the command prompt using the function `system2` in R and I got the following error:

```
system2("cmd.exe", args = paste("cd", "Users/AKatherine/Downloads", sep = " "))
```

> 'Akatherine' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Also, I tried to run this

```
system2("cmd.exe", args = "java -mx150m -cp "*;" edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser -outputFormat "penn,typedDependencies" -outputFormatOptions "basicDependencies" edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz ./Test/input.txt")
```

and got the following error:

> Error: unexpected ';' in "system2("cmd.exe", args = "java -mx150m -cp "*;"

Do anyone know why? Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I am fairly certain that you have a problem with escaping characters.  But there may be other problems as well.

Comment: Question: Does the command `cd Users/AKatherine/Downloads` make sense from the directory in which the command prompt would be opening?

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of my question, I tried using the `shell` function instead of the `system2` function and I got the same output that I observe when I type in the same command in the command prompt. I used:

```
shell(cmd = "java -mx150m -cp \"*;\" edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser -outputFormat \"penn,typedDependencies\" -outputFormatOptions \"basicDependencies\" edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz ./Test/input.txt", shell = "cmd.exe")
```

instead of

```
system2("cmd.exe", args = "java -mx150m -cp \"*;\" edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser -outputFormat \"penn,typedDependencies\" -outputFormatOptions \"basicDependencies\" edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz ./Test/input.txt")
```

Comment: I don't think `system2()` will work as you expect on Windows.  `shell()` is the way to go here.

Comment: Note that `system2` is perfectly usable and the better alternative, see my updated answer to your original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449241/running-windows-command-prompt-using-r/34449363#34449363

Comment: @CaringDev Do you mind explaining why system2 would be a better alternative compared to shell?

Comment: @Nana "system2 is a more portable and flexible interface than system, introduced in R 2.12.0. It allows redirection of output without needing to invoke a shell on Windows, a portable way to set environment variables for the execution of command, and finer control over the redirection of stdout and stderr. Conversely, system (and shell on Windows) allows the invocation of arbitrary command lines." (from [ETHZ man page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system2.html)), see also [R Manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/fullrefman.pdf)

Comment: @Nana `shell` is basically a windows only hack that was needed before `system2` was introduced.